# Batch faxing with Excel control of re-try attempts

Tags: excel, vba, fax, createobject

I use CDO to email faxes to efax.co.uk. I send multiple faxes at one time (maybe up to 10) to the same fax number. The problem is efax reports most of the faxes I send as unsuccessful because the fax number is busy (guess what, busy sending my faxes).  I checked with efax, it's not possible to configure the re-try time nor to queue faxes to the same number.

Therefore I would like to create a separate instance of Excel (maybe using CreateObject("excel.application") ), that has the background batch processing macro. This second instance I need to:

1. reference the worksheet in the first instance of Excel, for the list of faxes to be sent.
2. send the email/fax, again referencing information in the first instance.
3. change the colour of a cell in first instance to show it has sent the fax.

When I start the computer and open the first instance, I would like it automatically to start the second instance. Thus when I close the first instance I would like it to close the second instance also.

The macro I currently use to send faxes:

```
Sub faxTPD()
Dim iMsg As Object
Dim iConf As Object
Dim strbody As String
Dim Flds As Variant

vuser = Environ("USERNAME")
vweek = Format(range("ThisWeek"), "yymmdd")
vtenant = range("tblaccounts").ListObject.ListColumns("Name").DataBodyRange(range("statementrow"))
Application.StatusBar = "FAX TPD: " & vtenant

Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

    iConf.Load -1    ' CDO Source Defaults
    Set Flds = iConf.Fields
    With Flds
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "xxxxx@yahoo.co.uk"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "xxxxxxx"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
        .Update
    End With

strbody = "Hello Third Party Deduction Team," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "Please find following Third Party Deduction Application and Rent Schedule for welfare benefit tenant " & vtenant & "." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "Regards" & vbNewLine & _
          "Pritchard Property" & vbNewLine & _
          "T: xxxxxxx" & vbNewLine & _
          "E: xxxxxxxx@yahoo.co.uk" & vbNewLine & _
          "W: http://www.xxxxx"


vpath = "C:\Users\" & vuser & "\Google Drive\WR Tenant Statements\DWP\" & vweek

With iMsg
    Set .Configuration = iConf
    .To = "441978xxxxxx@efaxsend.com"

    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .From = """Pritchard Property"" <xxxxxxx@yahoo.co.uk>"
    .Subject = "Third Party Deduction Application for Welfare Benefit Tenant " & vtenant
    .TextBody = strbody
    .addattachment vpath & "\" & vtenant & " DWP TPD.pdf"                                                           ' DWP TPD request arrears payment £3.65
    .addattachment vpath & "\" & vtenant & " Rent Schedule.pdf"                                                     ' Rent Schedule

    If range("tblaccounts").ListObject.ListColumns("AST").DataBodyRange(range("statementrow")) <> "" Then
        .addattachment range("tblaccounts").ListObject.ListColumns("AST").DataBodyRange(range("statementrow"))          ' AST
    End If

    If range("tblaccounts").ListObject.ListColumns("DWP TPD").DataBodyRange(range("statementrow")) <> "" Then
        .addattachment range("tblaccounts").ListObject.ListColumns("DWP TPD").DataBodyRange(range("statementrow"))      ' DWP TPD permission
    End If

    .Send
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: How does the second instance help? Won't the line still be busy regardless where you send the email from? Can't you just send them more slowly?

Comment: yes I want to press a button in excel and excel send the faxes more slowly, say 5 minutes between each fax.  However, if this delay is in the current instance Won't this freeze the user also ? Hence the need of the 2nd instance, the 2nd instance can be used for the sending of faxes and the delay between sending the faxes, hence batch processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Applcation.OnTime` might be the way to go here. You can schedule a procedure to run at a certain time in the future. In the meantime, Excel works normally and the user can continue working.  If you want to send faxes every five minutes until you've sent them all, it might look like this

```
'Create variables that don't lose scope until the workbook is closed
Public gvaTenants As Variant
Public glTenant As Long

Sub StartFaxes()

    'put all the tenants in an 2d array
    gvaTenants = Sheet1.ListObjects(1).ListColumns("name").DataBodyRange.Value
    'start with the first tentant
    glTenant = 1

    SendOneFax

End Sub

Sub SendOneFax()

    Dim sBody As String

    'Send the first fax
    '   Some CDO setup stuff
    sBody = "Dear " & gvaTenants(glTenant, 1) & ":" & vbNewLine & "Rest of message"
    '   Finish up CDO stuff and send

    'increment to the next tenant
    glTenant = glTenant + 1

    'if we haven't sent the last one, schedule VBA to run this code
    'again in five minutes
    If glTenant <= UBound(gvaTenants, 1) Then
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 5, 0), "SendOneFax"
    End If

    'During the five minutes between runs, the user can Excel normally.
    'the next time it runs, the user will have to wait a few secs for it to finish

End Sub
```